# After an update laptop gets really slow

Tags: boot, updates, 22.04

My laptop is HP Elitebook 1030 g3. I bought this as second hand. It came with Windows 10. After one update first night, it became slow. It got slower and slower every day. And in the third day after the update, the laptop was really unusable (I actually had a potato laptop for last 8 years. So "unusable" for me stands for "really REALLY UNUSABLE"). It took more than 15 minutes to get to the start screen. And another 15 minutes to login. Then after logging in it was merely impossible to open one software. It was taking 30 minutes for any software to open where it was taking slip seconds to open after I bought this laptop. Turning that thing off was also a nightmare.

After trying many methods I finally decided to reinstall windows 10. After reinstalling it was again fine. But after the windows update every thing became the same.

Then I thought it was windows's issue. So I installed fedora (I was Linux user in my previous laptop). It was again running really smooth. But after the first update, it started to behave like windows again. Applications were taking 5 minutes to open, laptop was taking 10 minutes to start up and 5 minutes turn off. The update received an error this time though because of network connection loss. I re-downloaded and reinstalled that update in several ways, but it didn’t change my luck.

Then I thought it was fedora's problem with that update. After that I installed ubuntu. This time I avoided updates. It was running smoothly for last one and a half month. But that was untill last night when I attempted to update ubuntu. Again it failed for network issue. I turned my laptop off and that took more than 15 minutes. Today when I tried to turn up my laptop, it didn’t turned up! I waited for 30 minutes in the "press cntrl+c to skip file checks". I tried pressing every key in my keyboard and nothing just happened. So I forcefully turned that off. Again I tried to turn it on and it actually turned on after couple of minutes. But still it wasn’t enough as it was supposed to turn on in 5 seconds. I installed the update successfully. Application was again taking some time to open. I had difficulties to click on some buttons in the screen. Then I decided to see how it turns on again. So I turned off the laptop and this time it I was failed to turn it on after my 4th try.

So my question is, is it a bios or driver or hardware problem or is it a linux related problem?

Comment: If *every* OS gets progressively slower on the system by the day, I would assume it's not *updates* related and this is just a case of the system being old/ancient and probably hardware.  Especially if you have the same issue on Windows *and* multiple Linux distros.

Comment: ...and very likely a failing drive.

Comment: M.2 2280 slot is available to an NMVe or SSD, next time you have to be careful about ventilation. Do not cover the airflow intake and outlet. Keep cool the bottom of your laptop, if you live in a warm climate, an NMVe is not a good choice due to the heat comparing to an SSD.